# Power BI running total measure not working when no data for dimension

Tags: powerbi, dax

I tried to do a running total but I am struggling.

The problem is when there is no data for the dimension.

In the screenshot below, for 'Véhicule soumis', there is no data (i.e. Total = 0). In this case, the 'Running Total' returned is the grand total of 35 instead of 14.

The measures are:

```
Total = IF(ISBLANK(COUNTROWS(FactCreditApplications)); 0; COUNTROWS(FactCreditApplications))
Running Total = CALCULATE([Total]; FILTER(ALLSELECTED(FactCreditApplications); [StatusId] >= MAX([StatusId])))
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your table? May help with understanding the problem a bit more.

Comment: @RedVII, I can share but since the answer by Leonard solved my problem I have no need to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Running Total measure is using the StatusId from your fact table rather than your dimension table. Since the StatusId for 'Véhicule soumis' doesn't exist in your fact table, it behaves unexpectedly.

I'm assuming you have the StatusId column in your dimension table. If you do, it should simply be a matter of switching your measure to use the column in that table instead. E.g.:

```
Running Total = CALCULATE([Total]; FILTER(ALLSELECTED(DimStatus); [StatusId] >= MAX([StatusId])))
```

*assuming your dimension is DimStatus*

Comment: Oh, I was close! Now I understand better how to do measures. Clear explanation. Obviously, it works! Thank you very much!